# Dataclasses: trying to understand them in python

Tags: python, dataclasses

I'm learning classes in python. Also trying to learn dataclasses.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
class Person():
    name: str
    age: int
    height:  float
    email: str

person = Person('Joe', 25, 1.85, 'joe@dataquest.io')
print(person.name)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Person() takes no arguments
```

Unsure why.

Comment: Because you didn't decorate your class with `@dataclass`.

Comment: Idiot that I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't decorate your class with the `@dataclass` decorator you've imported, so it's just a plain old class that has a bunch of annotations but no specific `__init__`, so it inherits `object`'s `__init__`, which takes no arguments.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int
    height: float
    email: str
```

would have `dataclass` do its magic to read those annotations and add the constructor and everything else dataclasses do.

Comment: So bloody obvious. Thank you.